# Except Basic Authentication for some urls directories / files in

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication

I am trying to figure out one point in my development server.

I have linux server and having basic auth on that server. I am trying to remove that auth for certain folders / files. How I can achieve this?

`.htaccess` code below:

```
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/.password
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways you can do this, based on Apache version, the specific folders / files you want to allow and how your system is managed.

For example, on Apache 2.4 you could place the basic auth directives in an `<If>` container and use a negated regex/string comparison on the URL:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/folder(/|$)# && %{REQUEST_URI} != '/foo/bar.thml'">
    AuthName "Password Protected Area"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /var/.password
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

The above `<If>` expression is successful when the URL-path does not start with `/folder/` (ie. allows all files within) AND is not equal to `/foo/bar.html` (so allows that specific file).

#### Reference:

- Apache expressions: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html